# Adding more positions to angular bootstrap-ui

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Is it possible to add a position like `bottomRight` to angular `ui-bootstrap`?

[image]

if I do

```
.popover {
   &.bottom > .arrow{
    left: 80%;
  }
 }
```

The arrow will move. I just need to move the popup-content to left. I am new to angular.

Comment: inspect the source code of angular-ui to see what you need to do

Comment: Actually I've tried that. I need to extend the position method but don't really know how.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/4762) open in the repo where this feature implementation is being discussed.  Right now, only the primitive placements (top, left, bottom, right) are supported.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was able to do it with

> http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap

And [Bootstrap Aditions](http://github.com/mgcrea/bootstrap-additions)